# Cannot get name of running processes in windows

Tags: c++, winapi

I just want to display all running processes on the console.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
    HANDLE snap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(
        TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0
    );

    if(snap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        cout << "Encountered INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE\n";
        return 1;
    }

    pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    Process32First(snap, &pe32);

    do{
        cout << pe32.szExeFile << "\n";
    } while(Process32Next(snap, &pe32));

    return 0;
}
```

All I get is a bunch of `0060F810`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably trying to print a `WCHAR*` to `std::cout`. You might need `std::wcout`. In general, Windows (since 2000/XP) uses Unicode/UTF-16.

Comment: Or, use the `A` version of the API functions, `Process32FirstA()` and `Process32NextA()`, to match your use of `std::cout`.  But yes, you should prefer to use Unicode only.  Otherwise, if you use the `TCHAR`-based APIs (as the OP's code is), then consider doing something like this: `#ifdef UNICODE std::ostream &tcout = std::wcout; #else std::ostream &tcout = std::cout; #endif` ... `tcout << pe32.szExeFile << TEXT("\n");`